# GAS: Explanation of _cfi postfix

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, gnu-assembler

what does mean `_cfi` postfix in some GAS commands, e.g. `{pushl,popl}_cfi`?

Answer (score 1):

CFI stands for "Call Frame Information". The macros you're seeing are defined in [asm/dwarf2.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/dwarf2.h) and emit both a processor instruction and a corresponding assembler directive to produce the extra meta information for debuggers and exception handlers. See [here](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/gas-cfi/) for an example without the macros.